# Ruby/Rails - Bad URI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri, nokogiri

Not sure why I'm getting the following error when the URI works just fine in the browser:

```
http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin Bacon&b=Tom Cruise&u=1&p=google-apps
```

This is my code:

```
def kb(to)

    uri = "http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin Bacon&b=#{to.strip}&u=1&p=google-apps"
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(uri)) # throws error on this line

    return parse(doc)
end
```

I get the following error:

```
in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin Bacon&b=Tom Cruise&u=1&p=google-apps (URI::InvalidURIError)`
```

I execute the method in the following way:

```
kb("Tom Cruise")
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because a browser is pathologically friendly, like a puppy, and will go to great lengths to render a page or resolve a URL. An application won't do that because you have to tell it how to be friendly.

Your URL is not valid because it has embedded spaces. Replace the spaces with `%20`:

```
irb -f
irb(main):001:0> require 'open-uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> open('http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin%20Bacon&b=Tom%20Cruise&u=1&p=google-apps').read
=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n<link><actor>Tom Cruise</actor><movie>A Few Good Men (1992)</movie><actor>Kevin Bacon</actor></link>"
```

---

Escaping the characters needing to be escaped is easy:

```
irb -f
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> URI.escape('http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin Bacon&b=Tom Cruise&u=1&p=google-apps')
=> "http://oracleofbacon.org/cgi-bin/xml?a=Kevin%20Bacon&b=Tom%20Cruise&u=1&p=google-apps"
```

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks. I did the following, but I'm sure there's gotta be a cleaner way of replacing a space with %20: `#{to.strip.gsub(" ", "%20")}`

Comment: @Fulvio `require 'cgi'; CGI::escape("'Stop!' said Fred")  # => "%27Stop%21%27+said+Fred"` ([doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)). (or the `h` helper method in rails).

Comment: @Fulvio, I added code showing how to handle escaping the string. Using `gsub` is OK if you know only one character needs replacing. Beyond that you should take advantage of the pre-invented wheel and go with [URI](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/uri/frames) or the [Addressable](http://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/frames) gem, which is very full-featured.